# What proxy software would suit this puropse?

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-vista

Okay, I have no clue if anything out there meets these requirements, but I'd like a proxy (for personal use) that can meet these standards:

- Able to forward HTTP 1.1 traffic.  (HTTPS/FTP/etc. not needed)
- Able to *permanently* cache certain items.  (For example, if an item's expire date is >1 year into the future, write it to disk and read that instead of making a new request.
- Able to redirect (either silently or with a 302) certain requests based on the URL.
- Works on Windows Vista Home Premium x32.
- Is free (either freeware or free software will work).

Also, these features would be nice, but are not required:

- Supports logging requests
- Supports authentication

Answer (score 2):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is a pretty powerful proxy that should be able to do everything you want. I've never used it on windows before, but a quick google shows that [it is possible](http://markus.revti.com/2007/06/installing-squid-cache-for-windows/)

Answer (score 2):

As theotherreceive says, SQUID is a very powerful proxy and works just fine on Windows. It will even do LanMan authorisation. See http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/squid27setup.asp for my walkthrough of installation on Windows.

JR

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a big fan of the [Apache.org](http://www.apache.org) proxy solutions.  I'm pretty sure the type of caching you're looking for was added to the HTTPD server in version 2.2.4.